# How to configure Solr standalone in Production server with Rails application using sunspot gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I'm looking to deploy solr-8 in production as standalone mode with Ruby on Rails application. While running bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex getting this error

```
RSolr::Error::Http - 500 Internal Server Error
```

Any help would be appreciated!

using gem sunspot in development and is working fine with standalone solr-8 on local machine.

Solr is running in cloud mode. Please share the configuration which is used to talk to solr and rails for index

Comment: Make sure all the solr dependencies are working locally. Do you have jdk installed?
Also do post more error logs. It would be helpful .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really straight forward setup but took long time for me to resolve.
In standalone mode it is bit tricky to communicate with rails 
we need to copy `schema.xml` and `solrconfig.xml` to `server/solr/your-core/conf/`
as Solr-8 have some deprecation warning. Please carefully read warnings.
Once you copied files restart solr and run

```
rake sunspot:solr:reindex
```